# How to find all specific keys in multiple level NESTED JSON in one loop, and for every of them change value

Tags: javascript, angular

how to get the index number for every object inside the array. 
I have JSON with multiple nested arrays of objects, and I need to set to the POSITION key index number.

I get this JSON dynamically, and I need to loop thru the JSON and on every **POSITION** key need to set `indexOF()`  number to get object position inside array.

My problem is, how to find all keys with name `POSITION` and set `indexOf()` number for a value?

I know, and I try to get it in loop for every nested array, but is there any BETTER way? Faster way?

Here is [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bj9xyk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with nested `for loops`

Thnx

Here is JSON

```
{
    "id": 175,
    "name": "dag",
    "title": "dfgd",
    "page": [{
        "id": 551,
        "name": "page1",
        "title": "Page 1",
        "position": 0,       ---> here I need set index number for obj in this page array
        "questions": [{
            "id": 70,
            "name": "text1",
            "text": "Questitexton 1",
            "position": 0,         ---> here I need set index number for obj in this questions array
            "data": [{
                "id": 56,
                "name": "data",
                "position": 0,       ---> here I need set index number for obj in this data array
                "text": "Control 3"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 69,
            "name": "data3",
            "text": "data 3",
            "position": 1,       ---> here I need set index number for obj in this array
            "data": [{
                "id": 55,
                "name": "data2",
                "position": 0,       ---> here I need set index number for obj in this data array
                "text": "Control 3"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 552,
        "name": "page2",
        "title": "Page 2",
        "position": 1,       ---> here I need set index number for obj in this page array
        "questions": [{
            "id": 73,
            "name": "text1",
            "text": "Questitexton 1",
            "position": 0,       ---> here I need set index number for obj in this questions array
            "data": [{
                "id": 75,
                "name": "data",
                "position": 0,       ---> here I need set index number for obj in this data array
                "text": "Control 3"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 45,
            "name": "data3",
            "text": "data 3",
            "position": 1,       ---> here I need set index number for obj in this questions array
            "data": [{
                "id": 798,
                "name": "data2",
                "position": 0,       ---> here I need set index number for obj in this data array
                "text": "Control 3"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

My current attempt

```js
const animals = [{
  id: 175,
  name: "dag",
  title: "dfgd",
  page: [{
      id: 551,
      name: "page1",
      title: "Page 1",
      position: null,
      questions: [{
          id: 70,
          name: "text1",
          text: "Questitexton 1",
          position: null,
          data: [{
            id: 56,
            name: "data",
            position: null,
            text: "Control 3"
          }]
        },
        {
          id: 69,
          name: "data3",
          text: "data 3",
          position: null,
          data: [{
            id: 55,
            name: "data2",
            position: null,
            text: "Control 3"
          }]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 552,
      name: "page2",
      title: "Page 2",
      position: null,
      questions: [{
          id: 73,
          name: "text2",
          text: "Questitexton 1",
          position: null,
          data: [{
            id: 75,
            name: "data",
            position: null,
            text: "Control 3"
          }]
        },
        {
          id: 45,
          name: "data5",
          text: "data 3",
          position: null,
          data: [{
            id: 798,
            name: "data2",
            position: null,
            text: "Control 3"
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];

for (let data of animals) {
  for (let data1 of data.page) {
    data1.position = data.page.indexOf(data1);
    for (let data2 of data1.questions) {
      data2.position = data1.questions.indexOf(data2);
      for (let data3 of data2.data) {
        data3.position = data2.data.indexOf(data3);
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(animals);
```

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: Your indexes seem to be correct, what is stopping you from getting it to work? Also, are you generating the data?

Comment: @Icepickle problem is because it is nested JSON, and I need to made nested `for loops`, I want to try to check everything in one same loop...

Comment: So you want to iterate the main object, detect if it has an array as a value, then add the position of each item in that array, iterate that object, detect if it has an array as value, then add the position of each item in that array, iterate that object, detect... well you get my point I hope :)

Comment: @NinaScholz pls, why downvote, please read question... i change TITLE, mabey it was confused? - I can get this with multiple `for loops`, but I want to get this in (mabey) in one loop, and check whole JSON

Comment: Yes yes, I get point, but I hope that there is some BETTER way to get this....

Comment: Well, then I am not sure you got my point, it's just code that repeats, so you can use one function that is used to iterate all your objects sets the position and verifies if it has an array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210646/discussion-between-arter-and-icepickle).

Comment: @NinaScholz I added what i try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could clone the object and add the index if `position` is found.

```js
const addIndex = (o, i) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => [
    k,
    k === 'position'
        ? i
        : Array.isArray(v)
            ? v.map(addIndex)
            : v
]));

var animals = [{ id: 175, name: "dag", title: "dfgd", page: [{ id: 551, name: "page1", title: "Page 1", position: null, questions: [{ id: 70, name: "text1", text: "Questitexton 1", position: null, data: [{ id: 56, name: "data", position: null, text: "Control 3" }] }, { id: 69, name: "data3", text: "data 3", position: null, data: [{ id: 55, name: "data2", position: null, text: "Control 3" }] }] }, { id: 552, name: "page2", title: "Page 2", position: null, questions: [{ id: 73, name: "text2", text: "Questitexton 1", position: null, data: [{ id: 75, name: "data", position: null, text: "Control 3" }] }, { id: 45, name: "data5", text: "data 3", position: null, data: [{ id: 798, name: "data2", position: null, text: "Control 3" }] }] }] }],
    result = animals.map(addIndex);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: do you know why i get "Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'` for your example?

Comment: maybe you use an old user agent.

Comment: I update my tsconfig.js to "lib": ["es2019", "dom"], instead od 2018 and now it is working...thnx

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do it in a one-liner but if you create a re-usable function to set a position on an array, then you can do it quite quickly.

My code creates a copy of your original array, but that shouldn't be such a problem per say, I am sure you could work around it if you like

```
function getPositionedObject( objToCopy, position = 0 ) {
  // take all the keys on the object
  return Object.keys( objToCopy ).reduce( (agg, key) => {
    // get the value once
    const value = objToCopy[key];
    if (Array.isArray( value ) ) {
      // if it's an array, iterate all the items and re-use this function
      agg[key] = value.map( getPositionedObject );
    } else {
      // if it's not keep the value as is
      agg[key] = value;
    }
    return agg;
  }, { position }); // start with the position that was passed as a parameter
}
```

With your dataset (I removed the initial positions from the code you have given, it kinda looks like the following)

```js
const dataset = {
    "id": 175,
    "name": "dag",
    "title": "dfgd",
    "page": [{
        "id": 551,
        "name": "page1",
        "title": "Page 1",
        "questions": [{
            "id": 70,
            "name": "text1",
            "text": "Questitexton 1",
            "data": [{
                "id": 56,
                "name": "data",
                "text": "Control 3"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 69,
            "name": "data3",
            "text": "data 3",
            "data": [{
                "id": 55,
                "name": "data2",
                "text": "Control 3"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 552,
        "name": "page2",
        "title": "Page 2",
        "questions": [{
            "id": 73,
            "name": "text1",
            "text": "Questitexton 1",
            "data": [{
                "id": 75,
                "name": "data",
                "text": "Control 3"
            }]
        }, {
            "id": 45,
            "name": "data3",
            "text": "data 3",
            "data": [{
                "id": 798,
                "name": "data2",
                "text": "Control 3"
            }]
        }]
    }]
};

function getPositionedObject( objToCopy, position = 0 ) {
  return Object.keys( objToCopy ).reduce( (agg, key) => {
    const value = objToCopy[key];
    if (Array.isArray( value ) ) {
      agg[key] = value.map( getPositionedObject );
    } else {
      agg[key] = value;
    }
    return agg;
  }, { position });
}

console.log( getPositionedObject( dataset ) );
```